# Use pipe of commands as argument for diff

Tags: bash, grep, diff

I am having trouble with this simple task:

```
cat file | grep -E ^[0-9]+$ > file_grep
diff file file_grep
```

Problem is, I want to do this without `file_grep`

I have tried:

```
diff file `cat file | grep -E ^[0-9]+$`
```

and

```
diff file "`cat file | grep -E ^[0-9]+$`"
```

and a few other combinations :-) but I can't get it to work.
I always get an error, when the `diff` gets extra argument which is content of file filtered by `grep`.

Something similar always worked for me, when I wanted to `echo` command outputs from within a script like this (using backtick escapes):

```
echo `ls`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you're using bash:

```
diff file <(grep -E '^[0-9]+$' file)
```

The `<(COMMAND)` sequence expands to the name of a pseudo-file (such as `/dev/fd/63`) from which you can read the output of the command.

But for this particular case, ruakh's solution is simpler.  It takes advantage of the fact that `-` as an argument to `diff` causes it to read its standard input.  The `<(COMMAND)` syntax becomes more useful when both arguments to `diff` are command output, such as:

```
diff <(this_command) <(that_command)
```

Answer (score 53):

The simplest approach is:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+$' file | diff file -
```

The hyphen `-` as the filename is a specific notation that tells `diff` "use standard input"; it's documented in the `diff` man-page. (Most of the common utilities support the same notation.)

The reason that backticks don't work is that they capture the output of a command and pass it *as an argument*. For example, this:

```
cat `echo file`
```

is equivalent to this:

```
cat file
```

and this:

```
diff file "`cat file | grep -E ^[0-9]+$`"
```

is equivalent to something like this:

```
diff file "123
234
456"
```

That is, it actually tries to pass `123234345` (plus newlines) as a *filename*, rather than as the *contents* of a file. Technically, you could achieve the latter by using Bash's "process substitution" feature that actually creates a sort of temporary file:

```
diff file <(cat file | grep -E '^[0-9]+$')
```

but in your case it's not needed, because of `diff`'s support for `-`.

Comment: can I put whole command in test like this?

    `if [ -z grep -E '^[0-9]+$' file | diff file - ]; then
        echo "matches"
    fi`

Comment: @Pan.student: You actually don't need to use `[ -z ... ]`, since `diff` returns `0` ("success/true") if there are no differences between the files, and `1` ("failure/false") if there are any, so you can just write `if grep -E '^[0-9]+$' file | diff file - >/dev/null ; then echo matches ; fi` . . . and for that matter, you don't actually need to use `diff`, either, because `grep` returns `0` if lines are found and `1` otherwise, so you can just write `if ! grep '[^0-9]' file >/dev/null ; then echo matches ; fi` to confirm that there are no lines that contain characters other than `0-9`.

Answer (score 11):

```
grep -E '^[0-9]+$' file | diff - file
```

where `-` means "read from standard input".

Answer (score 7):

Try process substitution:

```
$ diff file <(grep -E "^[0-9]+$" file)
```

From the bash manpage:

> Process Substitution
>
> Process  substitution  is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of
>      naming open files.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The process list is run with its input  or
>      output  connected  to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd.  The name of this file is passed as an argument to
>      the current command as the result of the expansion.  If the >(list) form is used, writing  to  the  file
>      will provide input for list.  If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read
>      to obtain the output of list.

Answer (score 5):

In bash, the syntax is

```
diff file <(cat file | grep -E ^[0-9]+$)
```